# MySQL fail to start in Docker when mount /etc to host

Tags: mysql, docker

I use below command to start MySQL container:

```bash
docker run --name mysql-for-teamcity \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=FAKE-ROOT-PWD \
-v ~/MySQL/var_lib_mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
-v ~/MySQL/etc:/etc \
-p 3306:3306 \
-p 33060:33060 \
-it mysql
```

But MySQL won't start and complains:

```bash
ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"

mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-12-05T07:33:50.856816Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
2018-12-05T07:33:50.859460Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

If I remove `-v ~/MySQL/etc:/etc \` then MySQL would start correctlly.

Why can't I mount /etc to my host in Docker?

Comment: The `/etc/` directory is reserved for system configuration. Why don't you use proper directory? Like `/usr/etc/mysql` or any other? Or `/etc/mysql` at least. Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why are you mounting entire directory? Usually single `my.cnf` would do.

Comment: @emix thanks for your advice. I want to modify my.cnf. I have mounted /etc/mysql for once, but MySQL does not create my.cnf in that folder, so I want to try with /etc/my.cnf

Comment: If you want to modify the my.cnf mount single file only, not entire directory, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @emix I have tried to mount /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql again. Both are failed and error message is the same.

Comment: How did you mount it dude, I don't read tea leaves. I'm pretty sure you're doing it wrong. The location of the `my.cnf` inside the container is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` so I expect your mount arguments looks like this for example: `-v ~/MySQL/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Did you read the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) anyway? It's well explained everything.

Comment: @emix I want to modify the default my.cnf in the container. I just figured out that bind mounts cannot do that.  Bind mounts are used to mount a directory INTO the container, not OUT. This is my silly mistake, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is my silly mistake; it should be an [RTFM](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) question.

According to [Docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount), Bind mounts are used to bind directory **into** a container, not **out**.

So when I specified `-v ~/MySQL/etc:/etc`, the contents in my "~/MySQL/etc" would obscure the original contents in "/etc" of the MySQL image.

That's why mysqld failed while attempting to check config. Because the config does not exist in my "~/MySQL/etc/".

I leave the answer here in case someone else does not read the manual:(